# Render external loaded vue component in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I want to load external vue components in a react app as plugins from an url.

I already bundled the vue component as a commonJs package, but it will not render in the react app.

Comment: Never handled this use case, but this may be helpful if you're open to another dependency:

https://github.com/akxcv/vuera

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried this but I cant get it running. I will retry it again. At the moment I try to bundle it with roll as a full plugin.

Comment: This page has a good guide at the bottom on getting vue in react with Vuera. Looks like it may have bugs / outstanding issues according to the post (that was written in 2017)

https://x-team.com/blog/react-vue-component-integration/

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution

Vue Project

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import wrap from '@vue/web-component-wrapper'
import Plugin from './components/Plugin'
const CustomElement = wrap(Vue, Plugin)
window.customElements.define('vue-plugin', CustomElement)
```

./component/Plugin.vue

```
<template>
   <div class>
      <p>{{text}}</p>
      <p>{{pluginData.text}}</p>
      <button v-on:click="sendData({ text: 'primary click vue' })">primary</button>
      <button v-on:click="sendData({ text: 'secondary click vue' })">secondary</button>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
      props: {
      text: String,
      data: String
   },
   computed: {
      pluginData () {
          return JSON.parse(this.data)
      }
  },
  methods: {
     sendData: function(payload) {
        this.$emit('sendData', payload);
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then build the webcomponent with:

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --name vue-plugin ./src/main.js
```

And loaded in the react app with:

```
const $script = require("scriptjs")

$script("https://external-url-to-your-component.com/plugin.js", () => {
            this.setState({
                Component: ({ data, children, ...props}) => React.createElement(
                    'vue-plugin',
                    {...props, data: JSON.stringify(data), ref: elem => this[name] = elem },
                    children
                )
            })
            this[name].addEventListener('sendData', event => {
                const payload = event.detail
                payload && payload.length && sendData(payload[0])
            })
        })
```